# change tab color of dijit layout tabcontainer

Tags: css, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm trying to change the title text color of `dijit` layout `tabcontainer` for when the tab is both active and inactive.

Does anyone know what the css property names are for the tabcontainer title colors or where I might find them listed ?

I'm using dojo version `1.12`

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.tabLabel` css class to change the text color of the tabcontainer , also if you want to set a color in the active state of tab ,
just check with the `.dijitTabChecked .tabLabel` .

See below working snippet :

```js
require([
 "dojo/query",
  "dojo/on",
 "dojo/dom-style",
  "dijit/layout/TabContainer", 
  "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(query,On,domStyle,TabContainer,ContentPane) {
  
  var tc = new TabContainer({
    style: "height: 100px; width: 100%;"
  },"tabContainer");

  var cpOrg = new ContentPane({
       title: "Tabe one",
       content: "Content of tab 1"
  });
  
  tc.addChild(cpOrg);
 
  var cpShared = new ContentPane({
       title: "Tabe two",
       content: "Content of tab 2"
  });
  tc.addChild(cpShared);

  var cpPrivate = new ContentPane({
       title: "Tabe three",
       content: "Content of tab 3"
  });
  
  tc.addChild(cpPrivate);
  tc.startup();
 
  
  
});
```

```css
#tabContainer .tabLabel {
  color:green;
  
}

#tabContainer .dijitTabChecked .tabLabel {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="claro">
  <div id="tabContainer"></div>
</div>
```